# Relative paths in R for using different computers

Tags: r, relative-path

I use RStudio on multiple computers and I'd like to be able to access files across machines.

Right now I have to comment in and out wd paths depending on the computer but they are all referencing the same files on dropbox and it would be great to just be able to have a relative path so that I don't have to futz with that (admittedly minor) step every time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Read the file from the web instead reading local files? Symbolic links?

Comment: An option is to declare a global variable like `baseDir` and use this variable in combination with `paste` and the rest of the directory structure. In that case you only have to define `baseDir` once at startup (which could also be done using .RProfile)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123080/1664978